# Filter elastic search to only get items where a field is not duplicated

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a group-members index, where each "group member" has a role, an attached groupID and an attached userID. I'm trying to get a list of all Admin group members for a user where there are no other Admins for the group. So essentially, I don't want to get any group members back where there's another group member with the same group ID.

For example, given the following:

```
{"userID": "1", "groupID": "A", "role": "Admin"},
{"userID": "2", "groupID": "A", "role": "Admin"},
{"userID": "1", "groupID": "B", "role": "Admin"},
{"userID": "3", "groupID": "C", "role": "Admin"},
```

If I were user 1, I would expect to get `{"userID": "1", "groupID": "B", "role": "Admin"}`

The only way I found that I could get this information is by first making a separate query where I get all of the groups the user is Admin of, then in a separate query I get all Admins for those groups, then aggregate it and filter the aggregate, but this seems messy. I'm pretty new to using ElasticSearch so this might be pretty rough...

First of all, is there a better way to get this info? And second, how would I then filter the "hits" based on the aggregation response? The aggregation looks correct, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                         "groupID.keyword": {list of user's group IDs}
                    }
                },
                {
                     "match": {
                         "role.keyword": "Admin"
                     }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "aggs": {
        "groups": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "groupID.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "admins": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "userID.keyword"
                    }
                },
                "single_admin_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "totalAdmins": "_count"
                        },
                        "script": "params.totalAdmins == 1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edited to note: I am using AWS ElasticSearch for this, so there may be some limitations.

Answer (score 0):

How I understood your task
Input: userID
Output: Groups where the user is the only administrator

All you had to do was limit the aggregation to the user only and add another filter has_bucket_filter

Query

```
GET /admins/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "role.keyword": "Admin"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "groupID.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "admins": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "userID.keyword",
            "include": "1"
          }
        },
        "single_admin_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "total_admins": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.total_admins == 1"
          }
        },
        "has_bucket_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "total_buckets": "admins._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": "params.total_buckets > 0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "groups" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "B",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "admins" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "1",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```